# Paypal Express Checkout Don't Skip the order review step

Tags: magento-1.9

I am stuck in the paypal express checkout order review page.I enable the option of skip order review.But still after payment it redirects me to the paypal/express/review/  and then user have to submit order again.

Answer (score 1):

The "Skip Order Review" option will only work when the customers go through the magento checkout page and add their shipping address and click on "Paypal" option for the payment.

This will not work when you are adding "shortcut" buttons on the products page or the checkout page.

For more information you can refer to this link: [PayPal Express 'Skip Order Review Step' not 100%](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65230/paypal-express-skip-order-review-step-not-100)